# How to add angular event listener to svg?

Tags: angular, svg

I have the following template for my angular component:

```
<div class="center">
    <object id="img" data="assets/img/big_layout.svg" #svg></object>
</div>
```

I would like to trigger an angular event when the svg is clicked. I tried adding `(click)="onSelect($event)"` to the `<object>` but that didn't work. Is it possible to get the object with Renderer2, and then attach an event listener in the component?

Comment: There is no way to do that when SVG is added this way (also doesn't work with dynamically added HTML). You can query the SVG `querySelector(...)` and use `addEventHandler()` like with plain JS

Comment: Could you wrap the object in a div and attach the listener to that div? Assuming the click event will bubble up to the div

Comment: @LLai I tried this, but it didn't work - not sure if there are some css properties required to make this work?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards try adding `pointer-events: none` to the object element