# Click event won't trigger on click?

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, svg

I have the following html ( a template in my angular 5 component ):

```
<div class="center">
    <object id="img" data="assets/img/big_layout.svg" #svg></object>
</div>
```

In my component I have this:

```
  @ViewChild('svg') svg: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.svg.nativeElement.addEventListener('load', () => { // wait for the svg to load
      console.log('Clicked...')
    }, false);
  }
```

As expected, this logic works correctly - when the component loads, I get `Clicked...` logged for every instance of the component in the view.

However, as soon as I change the event from `'load'` to `'click'`, clicking on the svg doesn't fire any event?

Any idea why?

## Update:

As noted in the linked question, the following html doesn't trigger the click event either:

```
<div class="center" (click)="onClick()">
    <object id="img" (click)="onClick()" data="assets/img/big_layout.svg" #svg></object>
</div>
```

Here is a plunk [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/J5MbTmZKasO7jthSlJAK?p=preview)

Comment: why don't you use `(click)` event on your `object` div?

Comment: @Flow I tried that before and it didn't work... See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47097506/how-to-add-angular-event-listener-to-svg)

Comment: how did you tryed to use it?

Comment: html:
`<object  id="img" data="assets/img/big_layout.svg" (click)="clickerFuntion()"></object >`
ts:
`clickerFuntion(){console.log('Clicked...');}`

Comment: Did you try attaching the click to the `div` and not the `object` ?

Comment: <div (click)="funcion()"><object ..../></div>?

Comment: @Flow see edited question

Comment: @callback yes, see edited question

Comment: @Eliseo I tried this - see my update to the question

Comment: 1.Do you have any hostlistner or listener on document click in your project? 2. could you provide a demo as it's tightly inked on your setup?

Comment: @Vega 1. No (but I do have a hostlistener for laod event). 2. Here is a minimal [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/J5MbTmZKasO7jthSlJAK?p=preview) clicking on the svg should bring about the same "toggle background color" behavior as clicking on any of the other elements.

Comment: <img> tag works: http://plnkr.co/edit/XTBueObocotnkzFenFIW?p=preview

Comment: ~@Vega Annoyingly, I need to use Object tags, as another part of the component has to interact with elements of the svg

Comment: Things apart, click on div works, it's only object that 'ignores' it

Comment: @Vega I was thinking about whether there was some css trick that would make the div sit "on top" of the svg so that event could be picked up - but haven't been able to make that approach work?

Comment: Object 'cannot' be clicked : check out this answer and comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25916723

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158349/discussion-between-george-edwards-and-vega).

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that it doesn't work on your project, maybe due to the new angular 5 version.

You can achieve what you want by binding a `(click)` event directly on the template :

```
<div class="center">
    <object id="img" data="assets/img/big_layout.svg" (click)="onClick()"></object>
</div>
```

And by adding the method in your component file :

```
onClick() {
    console.log('Clicked');
}
```

**EDIT :** 
Object tags are like iframe, they can't be accessed for security purposes !

Comment: As noted in the linked question, neither having a `(click)` in the object or the div works...

Comment: Oh sorry, don't see it ! So it's weirder

Comment: Appart repeating what was in a comment (and in an other post already), this answer is not correct as the edit is against the first part